# What is the bias exponent?

Tags: system, computer-science

My question concerns the IEEE 754 Standard

So im going through the steps necessary to convert denary numbers into a floating point number (IEEE 754 standard) but I dont understand the purpose of determining the biased exponent. I cant get my head around that step and what it is exactly and why its done?

Could any one explain what this is - please keep in mind that I have just started a computer science conversion masters so I wont completely understand certain choices of terminology!

If you think its very long to explain please point me in the right direction!

Comment: Did my answer below help you? If so, I suggest that you accept it so that the question is marked als solved. If not, what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

The exponent in an IEEE 32-bit floating point number is 8 bits.

In most cases where we want to store a signed quantity in an 8-bit field, we use a signed representation.  0x80 is -128, 0xFF is -1, 0x00 is 0, up to 0x7F is 127.

But that's not how the exponent is represented. The exponent field is treated as if it were unsigned 8-bit number that is 127 too large. Look at the unsigned value in the exponent field and subtract 127 to get the actual value.  So 0x00 represents -127.  0x7F represents 0.

For 64-bit floats, the field is 11 bits, with a bias of 1023, but it works the same.

Comment: in case of 16-bit numbers shown in single precision floating point representation, what is the bias bit?

Answer (score 0):

A floating point number **could** be represented (**but is not**) as a sign bit `s`, an exponent field `e`, and a mantissa field `m`, where `e` is a signed integer and `m` is an unsigned fraction of an integer. The value of that number would then be computed as `(-1)^s • 2^e • m`. But this would not allow to represent important special cases.
Note that one could increase the exponent by `±n` **and** shift the mantissa right by `±n` without changing the value of the number. This allows for nearly a numbers to adjust the exponent such that the mantissa starts with a `1` (one exception is of course `0`, a special FP number). If one does so, one has **normalized FP numbers**, and since the mantissa now starts always with `1`, one does not have to store the leading `1` in memory, and the saved bit is used to increase the precision of the FP number. Thus, no mantissa `m` is stored but a mantissa field `mf`.
But how is now `0` represented? And what about FP numbers that have already the max or min exponent field, but due to their normalization, cannot be made larger or smaller? And what about "not a number-s" that are e.g. the result of `x/0`?
Here comes the idea of a biased exponent: If half of the max exponent value is added to the exponent field, one gets the bias exponent `be`. To compute the value of the FP number, this bias has to be subtracted of course. But all normalized FP numbers have now `0 < be <(all 1)`. Therefore these special biased exponents `0` and `(all 1)` can now be reserved for special purposes.

- `be = 0, mf = 0`: Exact 0.
- `be = 0, mf ≠ 0`: A denormalized number, i.e. `mf` is the real mantissa that does not have a leading `1`.
- `be = (all 1), mf = 0`: Infinite
- `be = (all 1), mf ≠ 0`: Not a number (`NaN`)